# supplied paramters do not match any signature of call target, because no overload accepts 1 parameters

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

After an upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 15.3 I am getting the following error:

[image]

The code transpiles without errors on the command line and if i remove the `x` arg in the `then` call the red squiggles go away ... but this is perfectly valid to have the x as an argument of `then`
Also changing `getFoo` to return `any` instead of `Promise<User>` also 'fixes' it

### update

This has now been identified as a [resharper bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465930)

please note the first few comments refer to an older example

Comment: Also 15.3 comes with TS 2.3.4, is that the version you're using to compile on CLI? Wonder if it's version differences.

Comment: @kamranicus my `tsc -v` is 2.3.2 - I updated my question to show the definition of `getUser` - I must stress it does *not* produce errors on tsc nor does the exact same file show any errors when loading using Visual Studio Code

Comment: @kamranicus updated my question with a simple recreate. perhaps delete your comment as it is out of context...(i will mine)

Comment: interesting! I can have exact same code in VS Code without any compiler errors. Do you have a tsconfig? VS still might be using a different version of tsc. In the csproj, you'll see a `TypeScriptToolsVersion`, what does it say?

Comment: @kamranicus that does not exist in my csproj perhaps because i am using tsconfig? even so, removing the tsconfig and doing it the 'msbuild way' does not make the problem go away. perhaps i need to clear a cache somewhere